# How can I see see what properties are being used in a function?

Tags: c#

I have a relatively large function that has 3 input parameters which include dozens of nested properties. I'm looking for a way to see which properties are being used from those objects, that way I can only pass in the required data.

```
private int FunctionWithTooMuchData(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

In the above example, I would want to know that `int d` was never used. This is a very basic example, so in my case there are multiple nested classes as input parameters.

Comment: In an IDE like Visual Studio just change the parameter name (edit `int d` to `int dTemp` or something) and VS will underline what's broken for you, and list it in the Error List.  That will be what you need to pass in.

Comment: A good question, but I'm not sure if there is an easy answer to it. VS Code and Visual Studio both can highlight unused variables or even warn on them, but as for the nested fields - I'm really not sure if such functionality is available anywhere.

Comment: It depends on which IDE you're using and the features it provides. It also depends on if you want to know this as you write the code, or during compile or runtime.

Comment: If it's a black box for you, then you could try to decompile it or do extensive black box testing to see which params have no effect on the result.

Comment: If it's your code and just really long then try and remove one. If it is unused, code will still compile.

Comment: Btw: that also should be a hint to you that the function is maybe _too_ long.

Comment: *"in my case there are multiple nested classes as input parameters"* - And you're looking to know which specific properties on those objects are being used, not just the input parameters themselves?  I doubt there's a meaningful way to do that.  At that point you're really just talking about examining and testing the code.  For each parameter **itself** you can simply remove it and the compiler will tell you if anything was relying on it.  But for properties within each object, and properties within those properties, etc. it's going to be a manual process.

Comment: @David & others, thanks for your comments. It seems like I may just need to go through manually to check for usage and then refactor.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you mentioned in the comments. Change this trivial example to a minimal version of your actual case, where a class object is passed and properties/fields are used and some not. Also add the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Unused parameters are automatic hightlighted in C# in visual studio. The parameter d would be highlighted in a lighter grey tone in your example. See [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/unused-values-parameters?view=vs-2022)

Comment: In my case the input parameters are classes, so I cant see what properties are actually greyed out unfortunately.

Comment: @emuller if you pass objects why does it matter which properties are used anyway? object creation should be decoupled from the method call

Comment: @emuller That's an entirely different case than the one you've originally posted.

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry if I was unclear in the example. I put in the text below it that the inputs were classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any modern IDE or text processor, you should be able to see by default lenses (small annotations) over the top of your declarations, including classes and properties.

You mentioned in the comment on the post that you are passing custom class objects as parameters, and want to know if their properties are being used or not. It works the same way.

Take the following code as example:

```
class Sample {
  public int Num { get; }
  public bool Truth { get; set; }
  public List<int> Seq { get; } = new();
}

// (...)

private static void MyFunction(Sample param1, Sample param2, Sample param3) {
    param3.Seq.AddRange(new[] { param1.Num, param2.Num, param3.Num });
}
```

In VSCode, you would see it annotated like this:

[image]

You can noticed how `Sample` is annotated with "3 references", which means that there are 3 places in the code where an object is declared with this type. You also can see how the property `Num` is annotated with "3 references" and `Seq` with one. That is because, in the function `MyFunction`, this is the amount of times those properties are referenced (either by get or set). Following that logic, you can assume that the property `Truth` is not used, and you could refactor it without breaking that function.